# no. of geom_point matches the value

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph

I have an existing ggplot with geom_col and some observations from a dataframe. The dataframe looks something like :

```
over runs wickets
1 12 0
2 8 0
3 9 2
4 3 1
5 6 0
```

The geom_col represents the runs data column and now I want to represent the wickets column using geom_point in a way that the number of points represents the wickets.

I want my graph to look something like this :
[image]

As

Comment: I'm interested to see what the answer is for this, since I have no idea! A cheat is to use a label for the wickets - 

`df <- data.frame(over = seq(1:5),
                 runs = c(12, 8, 9, 3, 6),
                 wickets = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 2))

df_conc <- df %>%
  filter(wickets > 0)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = over, y = runs)) +
  geom_col(fill = viridis(10, option = "B")[2]) +
  geom_label(data = df_conc, aes(x = over, y = runs + 1, label = wickets),label.r = unit(0, "lines")) + 
  theme_bw()
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, we'll need to transform your data to have one row per point. This method will require `dplyr` version > 1.0 which allows `summarize` to expand the number of rows.

You can adjust the spacing of the wickets by multiplying `seq(wickets)`, though with your sample data a spacing of 1 unit looks pretty good to me.

```
library(dplyr)

wicket_data = dd %>%
  filter(wickets > 0) %>%
  group_by(over) %>%
  summarize(wicket_y = runs + seq(wickets))

ggplot(dd, aes(x = over)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = runs), fill = "#A6C6FF") +
  geom_point(data = wicket_data, aes(y = wicket_y), color = "firebrick4") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

---

Using this sample data:

```
dd = read.table(text = "over runs wickets
1 12 0
2 8 0
3 9 2
4 3 1
5 6 0", header = T)
```